# Fluent UI Checkbox - How to NOT show check mark on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, fluent-ui

I am trying to use the Checkbox from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/checkbox.

By default, it will show the check mark when I hover on the checkbox (please see below), whereas I don't want to show that check mark on hover. Is there any props or styles I can set to achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this in your CSS this will be applied to all the checkboxes in your element.

```
.ms-Checkbox:not(.is-checked):hover .ms-Checkbox-checkmark{
  display:none;
}
```

In case you want to apply only for a specific checkbox make it a class like this

**Inside your CSS**

```
.custom-checkbox:not(.is-checked):hover .ms-Checkbox-checkmark{
  display:none;
}
```

**In your react component**
[Note] this example is from the Microsoft website you provided

```
<Checkbox label="Unchecked checkbox (uncontrolled)" onChange={_onChange} className="custom-checkbox" />
```